# Checking for at least one instance of keyword in list

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, boolean, clarifai

I'm using Clarifai's API in Python to get concept names from a photo and would like to determine if any of them match a local variable. The following command invokes a list:

```
In [1]:  p1_response = model.predict_by_filename(filename='PATH_TO_FILE')
         p1_concepts = p1_response['outputs'][0]['data']['concepts']
         for concept in p1_concepts:
         print(concept['name'])
Out [2]: street
         outdoors
         architecture
         travel
         city
         horizontal plane
         pavement
         road
         house
         town
         urban
         car
         no person
         building
         stock
         luxury
         traffic
         apartment
         business
         tourism
```

My local variable is a `keyword` defined as `"car"`. I tried running `if keyword in concept['name']`, but my console listed 11 `False`s before a `True`. Effectively, I'd like to make a function that does something if there is at least one instance of `keyword` in `concept['name']`. If anyone would chime in, I would much appreciate the help.

Comment: `any(word == keyword for word in concept['name'])`

Comment: @GarbageCollector I got a `'bool' object is not iterable` TypeError.

Comment: try again i have updated

Comment: Looks like concept['name'] is not a list, but a string with `\n`. Try this: `keyword in concept['name'].split()`

Comment: @Nish I got one `True`, but several `False`s.

Comment: it looks like your list elements have `\n` check my answer how to clean them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use any operator to check you `keyword` appears in any of the list memnber `concept['name']`

```
>>> keyword = "car"
>>> concept['name'] = ['car', 'carr', 'carrrr']
>>> any(word == keyword for word in concept['name'])
>>> True
```

However it is only applicable to list elements if they are not ending with `\n` to remove all `\n` use have to preprocess the list as follows:

```
>>> clean_list = list(map(lambda s: s.strip(), concept['name']))
```

Comment: Hmm. I preprocessed the list before using the any operator, and then ran an if-then statement to return True if any of the elements had the same value as the keyword, but I got the same output as before: 11 Falses before a True. How could I get the console to return True without the other False stamens if at least one instance of keyword exists in the list?

Comment: Its not possible unless your keyword is `list`. Can you post your exact solution so that I can check

Comment: Ok. I did a while statement that does something before breaking, which works for now. I was trying the following before: `clean_list = list(map(lambda s: s.strip(), concept['name']))`, `if any(word == keyword for word in concept['name']):`, `print(True)`, `else:`, `print(False)`.